# Distribution of number of inputs and ouputs per transaction over time

Tags: blockchain

How does the distribution of the number of inputs/outputs looks like currently ?

How did it evolved ?

Answer (score 2):

For non coinbase transactions, from block `[1000000,1500000]` grouped by `100000` blocks (green bars corresponds to "recently", i.e from block `1400000` to block `1499999` included).

[image: transactions 1]

[image: transactions 2]